# Git merge range of commits from cherry command

Tags: git, git-merge

Say I have two branches, A & B.  When I run

```
git cherry -v A B
```

I will get a list of commits that exist in branch B but do not exist in branch A.  In this instance, lets say there are fifty commits listed:

```
+ 53458a1a commit 1
+ de6e9b10 commit 2
+ 683f3ef2 commit 3
+ a9e8e23d commit 4
...
+ 127197fb commit 50
```

Is there a way to only merge the first four commits listed into branch A, without cherry-picking or rebasing?

When on branch A, I have tried:

```
git merge a9e8e23d
```

But that only gets me the fourth commit and it doesn't include commits 1-3.

I have also tried creating a local branch at commit 4:

```
git branch tmp a9e8e23d
```

But then branch tmp doesn't contain commits 1-3.

I am verifying if a branch contains the commits by running:

```
git branch --contains de6e9b10
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to only merge the first four commits listed into branch A, without cherry-picking or rebasing?

In case you want a specific commits in your merge you have to do it with `cherry-pick`, but the good thing about `cherry-pick` is that you can supply range in order to pick up more than one commit.

For example picking up the first 4 commits

```
# The .. marks the commits range.
git cherry-pick 53458a1a..a9e8e23d
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the help!  And how would you handle the case if there was a merge commit within that range?

I think you would have to specify a parent to cherry pick a merge commit, but isn't that the equivalent to just cherry picking parent commit directly?  Or is there just not any need to cherry pick a merge commit as long you get all of its parent commits?

Comment: The range `53458a1a..a9e8e23d` would exclude `53458a1a` itself (and be empty if these are in the wrong order), so beware of that. It's always wise to check the graph topology (with a graph viewer or with `git log --decorate --oneline --graph A B`, think of a DOG: Decorate, Oneline, Graph).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: "yes, if certain very commonly-met constraints are met."

> ... When I run
>
> ```
> git cherry -v A B
> ```
>
> I will get a list of commits that exist in branch `B` but do not exist in branch `A`.

Not quite: you get a list of *all non-merge* commits in `B` that are not in `A`, *prefixed by* a marker.  The marker is `+` if the commit in `B` has no corresponding commit in `B..A`, and `-` if the commit in `B` *does* have a corresponding commit in `B..A` (as determined by [`git patch-id`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html)).

If you just want a list of commits in `B` that are not in `A`, regardless of patch-ID equivalence, you would get these with:

```
git rev-list A..B
```

These are unprefixed, and *do* include merge commits (though you can add `--max-parents=1` or `--no-merges`, as `git cherry` does internally, to exclude merges).

> Is there a way to only merge the first four commits listed into branch A, without cherry-picking or rebasing?

Sometimes, but not always.

Note that you have specifically asked about *merging* these commits.  You also said *first four*.  There are multiple potential issues here, but let's start by looking at what it means to merge commits and/or branches.

The first thing to do is to draw (part of) the commit graph:

```
          A1--A2--A3   <-- A
         /
...--o--*
         \
          B1--B2--B3--B4   <-- B
```

Here we have two branch names, `A` and `B`, with three commits on branch `A` that are not on `B`, and four commits on `B` that are not in `A`.  There are also at least two commits that are on *both* branches, ending with the commit marked `*`, and including all earlier commits.

Using `git cherry -v A B` you will see these four `B` commits (with a shortened hash, and a subject line), prefixed by `+` or `-`.

To merge the entire branch `B` into branch `A`, you would do:

```
git checkout A; git merge B
```

This would, after finding the merge base commit `*`, try to combine all the changes from all the `A` commits with all the changes from all the `B` commits, and make a new merge commit on `A`:

```
          A1--A2--A3------M   <-- A
         /               /
...--o--*               /
         \             /
          B1--B2--B3--B4   <-- B
```

Note that this has merged commit `A3` (the tip of branch `A`, where you were after `git checkout A`) with commit `B4` (the tip of branch `B`).  This is how `git merge` works, when given a name: it finds the *branch tip* commit, and merges with the *current* commit—whatever it is you have checked out.

What you *can* do easily is merge any *earlier* commit than `B4`, *as long as* you want *all* the commits from there back.  For instance, to merge commit `B3`, you would:

```
git checkout B; git merge <hash-id-of-B3>
```

giving:

```
          A1--A2--A3--M   <-- A
         /           /
...--o--*           /
         \         /
          B1--B2--B3--B4   <-- B
```

It's even possible to merge `B2` (which includes `B1`), or just `B1` (which, since the branches join up at `*` anyway, *only* includes `B1`), e.g.:

```
          A1--A2--A3--M   <-- A
         /           /
...--o--*           /
         \         /
          ----B1--B2--B3--B4   <-- B
```

What's *not* possible is to merge `B3` without including `B1` and `B2`, or `B3` with `B1` but not with `B2`, for instance.  The graph inherently, automatically, includes *all* earlier commits once you make the merge.  (This is because the graph is actually constructed by reading each commit.  Reading merge commit `M` tells Git to look at `A3` as the first parent, and whichever `B` commit it was as the second parent.  It's then commits `A3` and `Bn` themselves that look back at `A2` and the previous `A` commit, and so on.

Now, because `git cherry` omits merge commits, we can get in trouble if the graph we just drew is too simple.  For instance, suppose the graph actually looks like this:

```
          A1--A2--A3   <-- A
         /
...--o--*    B2
         \  /  \
          B1    B4--B5   <-- B
            \  /
             B3
```

If we run `git cherry -v A B`, we once again see four `B` commits.  We *don't* see commit `B4`, because it is a merge of `B3` and `B2`.  We *do* see—in some order; we'll get back to this as well—`B1`, `B2`, `B3`, and `B5`.

Let's say you pick `B3` to merge.  This is very hard to draw unless I flip the lower half of the graph upside down, so I'll do that:

```
          A1--A2--A3--M   <-- A
         /           /
...--o--*           B3
         \         /  \
          -------B1    B4--B5   <-- B
                   \  /
                    B2
```

Look at the result: we've merged `B1` and `B3`, without merging `B2`.  That's probably not what you wanted.  We could merge `B2`, or we could merge `B4` to get the merged result of `B2+B3` (which is what's in `B4`) merged in to bring in all of `B1-B2-B3`.  But `B4` is not even listed in the `git cherry` output!

Now we come to the other problem.  What order are `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, and `B5` shown in?  What order *should* they be shown in?  If Git shows you `B1` then `B3` then `B2`, and you `git merge` `B3`, you get what you expect.  But if it shows you `B1` then `B2` then `B3`, and you `git merge B3`, you get what you *don't* expect: `B2` seems to be missing!

The actual order in which these commits are shown is not specified for `git cherry`.  If you use `git rev-list` instead of `git cherry`, you can control the order using `--topo-order`, `--date-order`, or `--author-date-order` (in practice you only need `--topo-order`).  You will still have potential issues with merges, so you would probably want to check, e.g., with `git rev-list --count`, whether you have backed up over any merges, or `git rev-list --merges --count`, whether there are any merges in `A..B` at all (whether or not you plan to merge from before or after that point).

The `--topo-order` restriction makes sure that child commits come before parent commits, i.e., that the listing goes in the `B5, B4, (B3 or B2), (B2 or B3 whichever was skipped), B1` order.  Adding `--reverse` reverses this order, and if there are no merges—as in the four-commit-long variant above—gets you the commits in their left-to-right order, so that you know for sure which revisions provide which histories.

In my testing, `git cherry` *seems* to list in reverse topological order—but there's nothing in the documentation that guarantees this, and from a quick look at the source code, nothing in the source either.  As noted above, you also get a marker for "commit is in the upstream as determined by equal patch IDs", but that should be harmless.  So the only real constraint is what's imposed by the graph, i.e., whether your "first N commits" really are the *first* N commits: no ordering issues, and no branching without a subsequent merge to recombine them.

#### Bottom line

If your `git cherry` output (which skips merges) had no merges to skip in the first place, *and* the output came out in reverse topological order, *then* you're definitely good.  Both are usually true—usually you're running this on a simple "branch B" that has no merges, and usually there are no issues with commits showing up in the wrong order.

In other versions of Git, I've seen commits come out in different orders, and it's not described in the current (Git 2.10/2.11) documentation as "always in reverse topo order".  And of course, you may be running on branches that contain internal branching.  So in this case, the answer is no.